# jQuery UI + Tabs + Google Maps

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, google-maps

So I know this is a common question, and yet I feel I have exhausted all the standard items out there.

I too have a problem with a jQuery Tab and a Google Map (2) inside a div.
I have implemented the position absolute + -10000px option.
I have implemented the $().bind('tabshow').... resizeMap();

I have had zero success with this issue.

I HAVE tried using the .load() with an external file that held my map, with great success, but it didn't seem like the proper solution as passing dynamic variables around didn't seem optimal.

```
<div id="contactTabs">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#maps"  title="Maps">Maps</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="maps">
    <!-- I have placed my Javascript in here -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=ABQIAAAA633BaQwEpWRjp-R1aATdPBT2yXp_ZAY8_ufC3CFXhHIE1NvwkxSkwAkIjGEiaeBEJXzobQZ3JjouCg"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.gmap-1.1.0-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $("#newMap").gMap({ 
          maptype: G_NORMAL_MAP,
          address: '--centering adddy--',
          zoom: 14,
          markers: [ ]                  
      });
    });
    </script>

    <div id="newMap" style="height: 400px;"></div>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance for some help. I know this has been an exhausting issue with the tabs and maps. Hope there is something that someone can help me with.

Cheers,[image]

Comment: Is there a reason your using the v2 of the Google Maps API? It has been deprecated in favour of v3

Comment: The only thing for this, is the fact that i'm using a jquery map plugin, and it currently is using v2 rather than v3...

Answer (score 1):

after you are creating the map, try just adding:

```
$("#newMap").height(100);
$("#newMap").width(100);
```

or something similar.

Comment: The only issue with this, as I forgot to mention, I wanted to have 100% width... this is just a pixel value. If I make a static width and height it works, but not a percentage...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize. But yeah that didn't seem to work either. 
the Dynamic height causes issues it seems.

Comment: Sorry mate to bother, but I did update the post with a picture... perhaps you would notice more of what is happening.

Comment: I am still not sure, but it looks like you rent closing your #maps div, you might want to do that.  If you move the map around, can you see more of it?  Or does it always just stay on 1/2 of the screen like that?

Comment: sorry, I meant to say you aren't closing your #maps div

Answer (score 0):

Place your Google Maps API

```
<head>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
        var map;
        function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
     </script>
```

Place this code into other JS file called in the bottom of your page

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#idOfYourTabButton').on('click', function() {
        lastCenter=map.getCenter(); //for center
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize'); //for resize
        map.setCenter(lastCenter); //for center too
    });
});
```

Hope that helped